# How to replace <NA> values with np.nan -- file imported using Pandas read_pickle()

Tags: pandas, numpy, pickle

I have created a `Pandas Data frame` by importing a `pickle ('P')` file using `pd.read_pickle()`. Below is the head info of the data frame. It looks like the `<NA>` values are created where there is no data. I want convert these `<NA>` values into `np.nan`.

```
sequels = pd.read_pickle('D:\Learning\Datacamp\Datasets/sequels.p')
print(sequels.head())
      id         title  sequel
0  19995        Avatar    <NA>
1    862     Toy Story     863
2    863   Toy Story 2   10193
3    597       Titanic    <NA>
4  24428  The Avengers    <NA>
```

I have tried using a few methods - `sequels.replace('<NA>', np.nan), sequels.fillna(np.nan)` and using regex - `sequels.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)`.

In all these cases, the  values are not getting replaced. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If replace missing values `NaN` to floats get `np.nan`, because in original column is used [integer na](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df['sequel'] = df['sequel'].astype('float')
print (df)
      id         title   sequel
0  19995        Avatar      NaN
1    862     Toy Story    863.0
2    863   Toy Story 2  10193.0
3    597       Titanic      NaN
4  24428  The Avengers      NaN
```

Solution with `replace`:

```
df['sequel'] = df['sequel'].replace({pd.NA: np.nan})

print (df)
      id         title   sequel
0  19995        Avatar      NaN
1    862     Toy Story    863.0
2    863   Toy Story 2  10193.0
3    597       Titanic      NaN
4  24428  The Avengers      NaN
```

Or:

```
 df['sequel'].replace({pd.NA: np.nan}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael :). It works. However, a query. The sequel column is int64 type; why is to be set float type?

Comment: @Srinivas - because `np.nan` is float, so if at least one `np.nan` then need floats in all values of column

Comment: df['sequel'].replace({pd.NA: np.nan}) - this does not replace the <NA> values. They remain.

Comment: @Srinivas - Also if assign back like `df['sequel'] = df['sequel'].replace({pd.NA: np.nan})` ?

Comment: or it works if we add 'inplace= True' to the replace method.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why replace solution doesn't work in my case, so I have to use apply with lambda:

```
df['sequel'].apply(lambda x: x if not pd.isna(x) else np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using replace:

```
      id         title  sequel
0  19995        Avatar    <NA>
1    862     Toy Story     863
2    863   Toy Story 2   10193
3    597       Titanic    <NA>
4  24428  The Avengers    <NA>
```

```
df['sequel'].replace({'<NA>': np.nan}, inplace = True)
```

Comment: this leads to 
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'str'